# Request for tag rename

Tags: support, tags

I tried to create a new tag, related to part 2 of my question, [m2-01al](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m2-01al).

I typoed it and the correct name is [m2-a01l](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m2-a01l) or uppercase if it fits.

Possibility to rename? I don't edit tag privileges yet

Comment: According to our naming scheme, that should probably have been called `huawei-mediapad-m2`. I couldn't find a way to rename tags (not even with mod powers). Could probably be done by a mod creating a new tag with the correct name, and then merge the two. Waiting for my mod colleges to approve – and the community to approve of the name :)

Comment: Related on the naming scheme: https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/could-it-have-sense-to-tag-devices-by-their-device-code

Comment: Check [these questions](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btags%5D+name+is%3Aq) on naming schemes ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one question with that tag. Simply remove the incorrect tag and create the correct one from that question. Unused tags are pruned from the system once per day.

Do note that tags are always all lowercase.