# Could it have sense to tag devices by their device code?

Tags: discussion, tags

Every Android device model is identified by a device code that is widely used (and potentially Googled, or at least returns a lot of results) among specialists/professionals.

E.g. Samsung Galaxy S3 is known with code `GT-I9300`, Motorola Nexus 6 is `shamu`, Huawei MediaPad M2 10.0 as `M2-A01L`

For the record, I have just tried to create a tag `m2-a01l` (typoed, I have a related question on renaming).

My question here is: does it have sense to create tags and/or synonims according to the device model code to help search engines find questions/answer on that model?

Consider that I took some time to start searching for `shamu rooting`, `m2-a01l stock firmware` etc. A number of topics on `xda` report the model code for the device in their `[tags]`, but XDA is a technical forum while Android SE is for everyone.

Those searches are *mainly* related to ROM stuff. I don't think people search for `how to uninstall app in shamu`, `shamu broken glass`

To be more clear in my question, it is my opinion that advanced users may *also* want to search for content by the model code, while everyday Android users/enthusiast may just prefer to use the model name

Any thoughts?

Comment: Thought: How many of our users do you think know their device's code name? I know it for one of my devices. Without giving an exact number: I have definitely more than one device. And with many users we can be glad if they can specify more than just "Samsung". Apart from that, it's not an exception if "almost similar devices" are grouped into one tag, as otherwise we'd end up with too many tags without meaning (used by less than 5 questions).

Comment: I don't think synonyms would have any impact on search results, so if that's the main reason for this suggestion I'm skeptical that it would be very useful. They don't appear anywhere in a question or its tags, they simply get translated into the "parent" tag, so I' not sure how a search engine would even know that a question's tags have any synonyms. Aside from that, I would agree with Izzy that the majority of users have no idea what their device codenames are.